# How read stdin of parent in child process

Tags: c, bash, process, pipe, fork

Here I have a program that works fine. This code runs a bash into the parent process and the child process saves stdout from parent process in file called 'toto'. So in the 'toto' file, there are all the outputs of the commands that have been run in the bash from parent process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
     int fd1[2];
     int pid;
     if(pipe(fd1) == -1){
        perror("pipe failed\n");
        return 1;
     }
     if((pid = fork()) == -1){
        perror("fork failed\n");
        return 2;
     }
     else if(pid == 0){
        close(fd1[1]);
        dup2(fd1[0], 0);
        close(fd1[0]);
        argv[0] = "-a";
        argv[1] = "toto";
        argv[2] = NULL;
        execve("/usr/bin/tee", argv,NULL);
        return 3;
     }
     else{
         close(fd1[0]);
         dup2(fd1[1],1);
         close(fd1[1]);
         execve("/bin/bash",NULL,NULL);
         return 4;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

I would also like to save in the 'toto' file the name of the command run into the bash.
Do you think it is possible and if so, how would you do this ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Note that `argv[0] = "-a";
        argv[1] = "toto";
        argv[2] = NULL;
        execve("/usr/bin/tee", argv, NULL);` tells `tee` that it's name is `-a`.  It will not have an argument `-a` so it won't append to the file `toto`; it will truncate what was there.  It also isn't clear that you have enough space in `argv` to create a list of 4 arguments (as you need `argv[0] = "tee"; argv[1] = "-a"; argv[2] = "toto"; argv[3] = NULL;`).  It isn't a good idea to give a command a completely empty environment; use `execv()` instead of `execve()` if you don't want to specify the environment.

Comment: Similar comments apply to `execve("/bin/bash",NULL,NULL);` — you don't even give `bash` a name, let alone any other arguments.  That's not a good idea either.  Again, use `execv()` and at least tell Bash it is called `bash`.  You might need to tell it to be interactive (`-i` option), though it may be OK as it still has the original standard input as its own standard input.

Comment: Consider whether using `bash -x` instead of `bash` (two strings, plus a null terminating pointer) and sending standard error as well as standard output down the pipe does what you want.  The commands would be prefixed by `+` instead of your prompt (or maybe as well as your prompt).  It's not quite the same.  Otherwise, you may have to investigate pseudo-ttys and have a variation of your program do all the logging.  I suspect it gets messy to do the job.